# trigonometric entity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

consider the function
$$f(x) = 2x + 4y^2$$
and the curve 
$$\gamma(t) = (\sin t, \cos t), \quad t\in (0, 2\pi).$$
Then, what is the derivate of the composite function $f(\gamma(t))$ in the point $t_0 = \pi$ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because you show no work of your own. You have asked enough questions on MSE to know that providing that information is the right way to ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this derivative either by:

- direct substitution of $\gamma(t)$ into $f(x)$ and then evaluating $$\left.\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}t}f\left(\gamma(t)\right)\right|_{t=\pi}$$
- using the chain rule first:
  $$\frac{\mbox{d}f}{\mbox{d}x}\frac{\mbox{d}x}{\mbox{d}t}+\frac{\mbox{d}f}{\mbox{d}y}\frac{\mbox{d}y}{\mbox{d}t} = \ldots$$

Comment: ok. Do you guide me in further steps?

Comment: Where do you get stuck or what answer did you find?

Comment: I'm using the chain rule.

Comment: If you include your attempt (you can edit your initial question to add this); it's easier to help you exactly where you get stuck. If you get stuck...

Comment: I come to the following:
$$2 \frac{dx}{dt} + 8y \frac{dy}{dt}$$.
here i'm stuck.

Comment: From $\gamma$, you have $x(t)=\sin t$ (so what is $x'(t)$?) and $y(t) = \cos t$.

Comment: Thanks. Answer is 2.

Comment: Almost; you should find $-2$; maybe you forgot the minus at $\cos\pi=-1$.

Comment: yeah its -2. Thank you alot.

Comment: @ethan Bolker 
Dear,
I was stuck in simple computation and eventually I get rid of the puzzled stuff.
Many thanks that you have pointed out about my question.